# Typeid behavior in c++

Tags: c++

Can someone explain to  me why this code prints Base , Derived but if i omit the f function from Base prints Base , Base ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std; 

class Base;
void testClassType (Base& b);
class Base
{
 virtual void f(){};
};

class Derived :public Base
{
};

int main ()
{
 Base b;
 Derived d;
 testClassType(b);
 testClassType(d);

}
 void testClassType(Base& b)
 {
  cout<<endl<<"It is:"<<typeid(b).name();
 }
```

Comment: I don't know the specific answer.  But it is worth pointing out that there are no guarantees made by the C++ standard on the contents of `type_info::name`.  So you shouldn't rely on it containing particular values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition of `typeid`, it returns the *dynamic* type of the expression for *polymorphic* types and *static* type of the expressions for *non-polymorphic* types.

A polymorphic type is a class type that has at least one virtual function.

In your case, when you call `testClassType(d)`, expression `b` inside `testClassType` function has static type `Base` and dynamic type `Derived`. However, without a single virtual function in `Base`, `typeid` will always report the static type - `Base`. Once you make your `Base` polymorphic, the code will report the dynamic type of `b`, which is `Derived`.

On top of that, as Oli correctly noted in the comments, the result of `type_info::name()` method is not guaranteed to contain any meaningful information. It can just return the same `"Hello World"` string for all types.

Comment: I would note that name() does have meaning with most common compilers. The standard says that the return value is `implementation defined` this means that the compiler must document its behavior. I think you find the both the MS compiler and gcc specify exactly what is here. As long as you check your compiler documentation to verify you will find the value is well defined.

Answer (score 2):

A class with at least one virtual member function is called a *polymorphic class*.

Each instance of a polymorphic class has (somehow) associated, at runtime, the original class used for instantiation. This is used by e.g. `typeid`. And also for calls of virtual member functions.

When you make the class non-polymorphic by removing `f`, then all that's known in `testClassType` is that it's a `Base`. No run-time checking of the type.

Cheers & hth.,